# Can't write to serial from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, uart, linux

I have the following items:

- ATMEGA328P-PU
- POLOLU - PGM03A (Programmer)
  https://www.pololu.com/docs/pdf/0J36/pololu_usb_avr_programmer.pdf

So far, I've been able to write output to data pins. Now I want to attach a sensor, but I need to see the sensor output on my computer.

I'm trying to make the micro-controller write 'K' character to TX pin and as far as I understood I should be able to connect to /dev/ttyACM0 using *putty* or *screen* from my Linux computer and see the output, but when I run the following commands, I get no output, I also tried ttyACM1, ttyACM2 but still nothing:

```
 putty /dev/ttyACM0 -serial 9600
```

OR

```
 screen /dev/ttyACM0
```

Code:

```
#define F_CPU     1600000UL
#define BAUD      9600
#define BRC       ((F_CPU/16/BAUD) - 1)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    UBRR0H = (BRC >> 8);    
    UBRR0L = BRC;

    UCSR0B = ( 1 << TXEN0 );
    UCSR0C = ( 1 << UCSZ01 ) | ( 1 << UCSZ00 );

    while( 1 )
    {
        UDR0 = 'K';
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC=/usr/bin/avr-gcc
MEGA=328p
CFLAGS=-g -Os -Wall -mcall-prologues -mmcu=atmega$(MEGA)
OBJ2HEX=/usr/bin/avr-objcopy 
PROG=/usr/bin/avrdude
TARGET=serial

program : $(TARGET).hex
    $(PROG) -c avrispv2 -p m$(MEGA) -P /dev/ttyACM0 -e
    $(PROG) -c avrispv2 -p m$(MEGA) -P /dev/ttyACM0 -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex

%.obj : %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.hex : %.obj
    $(OBJ2HEX) -R .eeprom -O ihex $< $@

clean :
    rm -f *.hex *.obj *.o
```

When I run the micro-controller I see the TX LED blinking, so I'm guessing the micro-controller is actually sending the data, but I'm just not reading it correctly on the computer side. Any suggestions?

Comment: TX on the micro = RX on the programmer, and vice versa. Is this how you have it hooked up?

Comment: @Cheibriados I placed the micro-controller into the Arduino Uno 'case' and connected the cable from USB programmer to Arduino schematic (so I don't have to do the wiring on the breadboard) like this: http://yourduino.com/sunshop2/images/products/large_114_TinyISP-3.jpg but I'm using different programmer

Comment: @Cheibriados Do I need to flip the TX/RX wires in the cable to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, even though I tried this device before, now suddenly I see output:

```
cu -l /dev/ttyACM2 -s 9600
```

but before that I ran

```
echo '12' > /dev/ttyACM2
```

As far as I understood, I needed to send two sequential bytes to open the connection.